# Problems with update Queries with join

Tags: mysql, performance, join

I have two tables named TempTable and AnotherTable which has the following structure as defined below. Also, I have given some sample row contents for both the table below.

**TempTable Definition**

```
CREATE TABLE `TempTable` (
  `ROWNUMBER` bigint(19) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `email` text,
  `someid` bigint(19) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mappedid` bigint(19) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ROWNUMBER`),
  KEY `IDX_1` (`email`(100))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**AnotherTable Definition**

```
CREATE TABLE `AnotherTable` (
  `primaryid` bigint(19) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `email` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`primaryid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**mysql>** `Select * from TempTable;`

```
+-----------+----------------------+--------+----------+
| ROWNUMBER | email                | someid | mappedid |
+-----------+----------------------+--------+----------+
|         1 | email1@somewhere.com |    101 |     NULL |
|         2 | email1@somewhere.com |    102 |     NULL |
|         3 | email1@somewhere.com |    103 |     NULL |
|         4 | email1@somewhere.com |    104 |     NULL |
|         5 | email2@somewhere.com |    105 |     NULL |
|         6 | email2@somewhere.com |    106 |     NULL |
|         7 | email2@somewhere.com |    107 |     NULL |
|         8 | email3@somewhere.com |    108 |     NULL |
+-----------+----------------------+--------+----------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**mysql>** `Select * from AnotherTable;`

```
+-----------+----------------------+
| primaryid | email                |
+-----------+----------------------+
|       201 | email1@somewhere.com |
|       202 | email1@somewhere.com |
|       203 | email1@somewhere.com |
|       204 | email2@somewhere.com |
+-----------+----------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here, in TempTable, the column mappedid is related to primaryid on AnotherTable. My aim here is to update the mappedids on TempTable based on email matching with TempTable and AnotherTable. I need to match 
based on "email" field only. So, my desired result would be somewhat as follows :

**mysql>** `Select * from TempTable;`

```
+-----------+----------------------+--------+----------+
| ROWNUMBER | email                | someid | mappedid |
+-----------+----------------------+--------+----------+
|         1 | email1@somewhere.com |    101 |     201  |
|         2 | email1@somewhere.com |    102 |     202  |
|         3 | email1@somewhere.com |    103 |     203  |
|         4 | email1@somewhere.com |    104 |     NULL |
|         5 | email2@somewhere.com |    105 |     204  |
|         6 | email2@somewhere.com |    106 |     NULL |
|         7 | email2@somewhere.com |    107 |     NULL |
|         8 | email3@somewhere.com |    108 |     NULL |
+-----------+----------------------+--------+----------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here, 201,202,203,204 all occur only once and the others which are not mapped should be null. There should not be any duplicate mappedids in TempTable.

**NOTE:** *In real-world I think it is not advisable to do a select query on AnotherTable as the number of records would be in millions. So, I am looking for an alternative/efficient way by which I could 
update the data in TempTable. TempTable is a temporary table and any number of operations on the temporary table are welcome.*

**mysql>** `update TempTable inner join AnotherTable
on TempTable.email= AnotherTable.email and TempTable.email!=''
set TempTable.mappedid=AnotherTable.primaryid
WHERE TempTable.mappedid is null;`

Query OK, 7 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 7  Changed: 7  Warnings: 0

**mysql>** `Select * from TempTable;`

```
+-----------+----------------------+--------+----------+
| ROWNUMBER | email                | someid | mappedid |
+-----------+----------------------+--------+----------+
|         1 | email1@somewhere.com |    101 |      201 |
|         2 | email1@somewhere.com |    102 |      201 |
|         3 | email1@somewhere.com |    103 |      201 |
|         4 | email1@somewhere.com |    104 |      201 |
|         5 | email2@somewhere.com |    105 |      204 |
|         6 | email2@somewhere.com |    106 |      204 |
|         7 | email2@somewhere.com |    107 |      204 |
|         8 | email3@somewhere.com |    108 |     NULL |
+-----------+----------------------+--------+----------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I tried by the above update query with inner join. But it created duplicate mappedid entries on TempTable as shown above. To remove the redundant entries, the current option I have is to nullify all duplicate entries and do a select on AnotherTable based on email. Say after removing redundant entries the table would look like this :

**mysql>** `Select * from TempTable;`

```
+-----------+----------------------+--------+----------+
| ROWNUMBER | email                | someid | mappedid |
+-----------+----------------------+--------+----------+
|         1 | email1@somewhere.com |    101 |      201 |
|         2 | email1@somewhere.com |    102 |     NULL |
|         3 | email1@somewhere.com |    103 |     NULL |
|         4 | email1@somewhere.com |    104 |     NULL |
|         5 | email2@somewhere.com |    105 |      204 |
|         6 | email2@somewhere.com |    106 |     NULL |
|         7 | email2@somewhere.com |    107 |     NULL |
|         8 | email3@somewhere.com |    108 |     NULL |
+-----------+----------------------+--------+----------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**mysql>** `Select * from AnotherTable;`

```
+-----------+----------------------+
| primaryid | email                |
+-----------+----------------------+
|       201 | email1@somewhere.com |
|       202 | email1@somewhere.com |
|       203 | email1@somewhere.com |
|       204 | email2@somewhere.com |
+-----------+----------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then, I have to do a "Select primaryid from AnotherTable where email='email1@somewhere.com' " and then based the ResultSet content I have to update the mappedid in TempTable. The problem is that since I have 2 duplicate emails (email1@somewhere.com and email2@somewhere.com), I need query AnotherTable 2 times. But, if the number of duplicates increases to say 100, it basically means I have to query AnotherTable which is already a heavy table 100 times (BTW email column would be indexed in AnotherTable). I know this is not the correct solution for this. Could you guys please help me out in coming up with an efficient solution when dealing with huge number of records ?

Comment: You have 500 reputation and still do't know how to post a question with correctly formated??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact is that `email` column on its own is not sufficient to join your tables properly. Additionally you need some sort of a positional number per each email.

```sql
SET @n1 := 0, @g1 := NULL;
SET @n2 := 0, @g2 := NULL;

UPDATE temptable t JOIN
(
  SELECT a.rownumber, b.primaryid
    FROM
  (
    SELECT rownumber, email, @n1 := IF(@g1 = email, @n1 + 1, 1) rnum, @g1 := email
      FROM temptable
     ORDER BY email, rownumber
  ) a LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT primaryid, email, @n2 := IF(@g2 = email, @n2 + 1, 1) rnum, @g2 := email
      FROM anothertable
     ORDER BY email, primaryid
  ) b 
      ON a.email = b.email 
     AND a.rnum = b.rnum
   WHERE b.primaryid IS NOT NULL
) s 
    ON t.rownumber = s.rownumber
   SET t.mappedid = s.primaryid;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/57efb/1)** demo

Comment: Really sorry for the late reply. This query gives me the correct solution :). But I have a few doubts, 1.) I really couldn't understand this part ("(at)n1 := IF(at)g1 = email, (at)n1 + 1, 1) rnum, (at)g1 := email"). Could you please explain a bit more on this? 2.) Also, I see that we are issuing a select query on anothertable and that too by using "order by" clause. Assuming that the anothertable consists of millions of records, won't that create a performance problem ?

Comment: 1) `@n1 := IF(@g1 = email, @n1 + 1, 1) rnum, @g1 := email` along with a proper `ORDER BY` in both subqueries produces row number for each row in the result sets that is needed to be able to join your tables (since you don't have any common columns that can be used for that). 2) If you work with millions of records you should consider to change the schema design to be able to join tables easily with support of indices. 3) If my answer gave the correct results and was helpful please consider to **[accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** it.

Comment: Yes it did help me :). Sorry for the delay. I just wanted to get my doubts clarified. Thanks a lot for the help :)